# What does "24 votes remaining to close" mean?

Tags: discussion

When I bring up the dialog to close a question, at the bottom it says "24 votes remaining to close".  Obviously this doesn't refer to the number of votes required to close the question since only five are needed.

Is this the number of votes *I* have available to close questions?  If so, how or when does the number get reset?

I looked in the FAQ for both the site and here on meta, and couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the number of votes to close *you* have remaining. It is similar to the maximum Q&A votes and flags in that it resets every 24 hours. Right now, with our site size and volume, you would only exhaust those close votes if you went through a full review queue... it shouldn't be an issue.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#close

Comment: Thanks, as I said I looked at the FAQ but somehow missed the part at the bottom that addresses this.